How to optimize a single index in a PyTorch tensor?
I have code like this optimizing an (N,3) tensor.
deform_verts = torch.full(verts_shape, 0.0, device=device, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([deform_verts], lr=5e-2, momentum=0.9)

However, what I really want is to optimize a single index.
deform_verts = torch.full(verts_shape, 0.0, device=device, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([deform_verts[275][1]], lr=5e-2, momentum=0.9)


ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor

How can I optimize this single index?
